# Controller 'Init' Function Executed More Than Once

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller

```
//init
var init = function () {

    $scope.getAlbumList();

};    

$scope.getAlbumList = function () {

    AlbumService.getAlbumList()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.albumList = data;
    });

};

$scope.viewAlbum = function () {

    AlbumService.getAlbum()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.album = data;
            $location.path("/album");
        });               

};

init();
```

and this is my routeProvider

```
   when('/albums', {
        templateUrl: 'WebApp/albums.html',
        controller: 'AlbumController'

    }).


    when('/album', {
        templateUrl: 'WebApp/albumview.html',
        controller: 'AlbumController'
    }).
```

So the AlbumController handles both the albums and albumview pages. 
When the controller is created, the `init` function is called which in turns calls the `getAlbumList` function.

The problem is that the controller is created again when the user clicks an album to go to its albumview page. This ends up executing the init function again which in turns causes an undesired second call to getAlbumList.

So basically, I need getAlbumList to be called when the controller is created for '/albums' but not '/albumview'.

How can I achieve this?
Obviously, I could solve this problem by creating a second controller for `/albumview` but this seems unnecessary and I'd rather have everything regarding albums in one controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

1. in your controller test if location.path() == 'albums'
2. in the html page of albums `ng-init="getAlbumList()"`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the quickest option is to check the path to see if you're in album or albums.  Here is sample code of how to do that:

```
if ($location.url().toLowerCase() === '/albums') {
  // call to getAlbumList here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will happen if you have `controller: 'AlbumController'` in router and your html have `ng-controller = "AlbumController"`. Use only one to avoid double initilization.